# Is there a way to redirect one directory as a root and its siblings as sub directories only via Apache2.4 mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, http, web, redirect, mod-rewrite

I must configure an HTTPD Server to serve main site from one of many sub directories, keeping all other to resolve as site sub catalogs. To make it more clear, lets say my root directory looks like this:

```
/var/www/
˫module_1
˫module_2
˫module_3
˫html
```

And the URL I want to have is:

```
example.com/module1 -> gets data from module_1 directory
example.com/module2 -> gets data from module_2 directory
example.com/module3 -> gets data from module_3 directory
example.com/ -> gets data from html directory
```

I tried some solution from the web, but it ends up wrong, like redirecting all to **html** or trying to find *module* data in **html** folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code your reference :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory "/var/www/">  
Options +Indexes  
AllowOverride None  
Order allow,deny  
Allow from all  
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank You for response, yet I probably will need to refactor this app, as it will cause a lot of problems in the future. And ```Options +Indexes``` may cause to show my files structure to users and that I find dangerous.